# MongoDB - Switch servers on replica set

Tags: mongodb

I've set up 2 machines running MongoDB ( O.S. Windows ) and i've set the replication. I was wondering if it's possible to kill the process that is running as **primary** to check if the **secondary** will turn as **primary**.

Is it possible? How? I just killed the primary process and on my mongo client ( that is connected to primary ), it didn't turned to secondary server.

Thank in advance.

Comment: You could connect to both servers and switch when the connection fails.

Comment: Is your client the mongo shell or something else?

Comment: How many mongodb instances are running? You need to have atleast 3 (Odd number) instances running to make the auto fail-over happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have at least a 3 members configuration.

[Replica documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/)

Set a correct replica, connect your mongoshell to the primary instance and shut it down ([Shutdown](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/shutdown/)), connect your mongoshell with a secondary and check replica set's status ([RS Status](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#dbcmd.replSetGetStatus)).

That's all !

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a third server as an arbitrer.

The arbitrer is the one that determinates which of the other servers will be primary.

Usually, it is recomended that each replica set have an odd number of servers(the miniumun would be 1 primary, 1 secondary, 1 arbitrer)

This might help you.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/

The arbitrer can be in a very tiny server, since it does not stores data, its only function is to decide.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to shutdown your primary (assuming that **primarydb** is your primary and **secondaryDB** is your secondary. The process would be as follow

1. Connect to your primary and secondaries.
2. Stop the primary.
3. Look at your secondaries if a new primary is elected.

Connect to your primary in the shell

```
conn1 = new Mongo("localhost:31000")
primaryDB = conn1.getDB("test")
```

Connect to your secondaries

```
conn2 = new Mongo("localhost:31001")
secondaryDB = conn2.getDB("test")
...
```

Shutdown your primary

```
primaryDB.adminCommand({"shutdown" : 1})
```

Check if one of the secondaries is elected as the primary

```
secondaryDB.isMaster()
```

In the result of the last operation you will see which server is now the new primary (look out for the **primary** key).

As mentioned in the comments, you should have at least three servers (one primary, two secondaries) to get the election process working.